# lint-staged no stage files match

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, lint-staged

Used create-react-app template. Windows, OpenServer.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "league-finder",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
    "eslint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.7.0",
    "husky": "^1.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3"
  }
}
```

.lintstagedrc

```
{  
  "*.js": ["eslint --fix", "git add"],
}
```

Result: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XexQ.png)

Why "No staged files match *.js"?

Comment: it is not clear what are you asking. variants: "is it something I should fix or just ignore?", "But I definitely added some files to stage. What's wrong with linter?", "What is stage at all?", "Why lint-staged checks only files in stage?" or maybe somerthing else - all them are about completely different things

Comment: Did you stage any js files using `git add`? it wasn't clear from the question.